# Plot the MajorAxisLength and the MinorAxisLength - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I found this script below in https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/30/visualizing-regionprops-ellipse-measurements/

I wish to plot also the MajorAxisLength and the MinorAxisLength, how can I do it?

Script:

```
url = 'https://blogs.mathworks.com/images/steve/2010/rice_binary.png';
bw = imread(url);
imshow(bw)

s = regionprops(bw, 'Orientation', 'MajorAxisLength', ...
    'MinorAxisLength', 'Eccentricity', 'Centroid');

imshow(bw)
hold on

phi = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
cosphi = cos(phi);
sinphi = sin(phi);

for k = 1:length(s)
    xbar = s(k).Centroid(1);
    ybar = s(k).Centroid(2);

    a = s(k).MajorAxisLength/2;
    b = s(k).MinorAxisLength/2;

    theta = pi*s(k).Orientation/180;
    R = [ cos(theta)   sin(theta)
         -sin(theta)   cos(theta)];

    xy = [a*cosphi; b*sinphi];
    xy = R*xy;

    x = xy(1,:) + xbar;
    y = xy(2,:) + ybar;

    plot(x,y,'r','LineWidth',2);
end
hold off
```

Comment: A length can not be plotted! its a measure

Comment: Do you mean you want to display `MajorAxisLength` and `MinorAxisLength` every time the for loop iterates?

Comment: What do you want your x and y axis to be?  Are you trying to plot major vs. Minor?

Comment: I wish plot both MajorAxisLength and MinorAxisLength of the objects. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not clear.  What is your x axis and what is your y axis?

Comment: x = MinorAxisLength and y axis = MajorAxisLength

Comment: Jane: `plot([x x],[y_min y_max]); plot([x_min x_max],[y y]);`Choose `x_min`, `x_max`, `y_min`, `y_max` so it fits your final plot.

Comment: Can you please extend what do you mean by "Choose x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max so it fits your final plot".

Comment: @elyraz, I mean, for example, if the final plot has axis([0 150 -100 200]), y_min will be -100, y_max = 200, x_min = 0, x_max = 150. But I'm not sure I understand jane's question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of unnecessary code in what you posted.  I don't think you actually attempted to adjust it for what you say you want to plot. Given what you said you are trying to do in the comments, I think this is the code you want in order to plot the Major Axis Length vs. Minor Axis Length

```
url = 'https://blogs.mathworks.com/images/steve/2010/rice_binary.png';
bw = imread(url);

s = regionprops(bw, 'Orientation', 'MajorAxisLength', ...
    'MinorAxisLength', 'Eccentricity', 'Centroid'); %Get region props

 Major=zeros(size(s)); 
 Minor=zeros(size(s));

for k = 1:length(s)
    Major(k)= s(k).MajorAxisLength; %get your y values
    Minor(k)= s(k).MinorAxisLength; %get your x values
end

figure %create a new figure because you don't want to plot on top of the image

plot(Minor, Major, 'o') %plot
xlabel('Minor Axis Length')
ylabel('Major Axis Length')
```